# Querying SQL Server on column hashed with MD5

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, md5, ssms

I have one `nvarchar` column in SQL Server which stores passwords hashed in MD5. I want to query on this column for testing purpose. I used SQL Server Management Studio to perform query something like this.

```
select * from users where Password = HASHBYTES('MD5','password');
```

I remember using such query in MYSQL, but I don't know how to do it in SQL Server.

Note please: I am not asking for converting from MD5 to plain. I just want to test that my application is correctly hashing the password.

Edit:
I use the following for generating the MD5 hash

```
using System.Web.Security;
....
FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(stringToEncrypt, "MD5");
```

Comment: What happens when you run the query? Why isn't the hash stored as `VARBINARY`?

Comment: Query runs but 0 rows are returned. I am not very sure about the possible implications of using VARCHAR instead of VARBINARY. Actually I used database generated from Code First Entity Model. In that EntityModel, I used string as password field and it generated VARCHAR column for the field in the Database.

Comment: Now that you've decided to use a hashed password instead of a string (this is a good thing by the way!), it might be time to consider updating the database schema to reflect that. I wish I could tell you how to do that using CFEM but my instinct is always going to be Design First Code Later.

Comment: You are doing the hashing where? Before you put the value into the field in the EM object?

Comment: @Chris, I have edited my question to include the code for generating the hash. I take the input from user page (asp.net mvc3), then hash it in MD5, and then store hash in the Entity Model field. The model is then persisted to database using the codefirst approach.

Answer (score 0):

Same function in SQL Server, but the return value is varbinary, not varchar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx

EDIT: Based on your question edit, I'd recommend changing your object and database to store a byte array, not a string.  That would keep things cleaner, and you'd be able to query the database using the HashBytes function.  To do that, you can use the EF field type "Binary".  To generate the value, use the ComputeHash method of the MD5 class- that's what your current method is doing anyway.

Comment: I will try making changes suggested by you. I will let you know once I succeed. Thanks for the help